# Bijective Pairing given one set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

****Disclaimer this is a homework help question not sure if that's a problem but I'll try to format my question in a way so I'm not just trying to get the answer but get some understanding of what it is I need to do to solve the question properly

### The Question

How many ordered lists of four natural numbers, $(a,b,c,d) \in N^4$, are there such that $a + b + c + d = 23$

- Describe how to encode/decode each ordered list into a codeword.

  - Why the encoding is a bijective pairing
  - How to count the number of codewords to answer the question

### What I know

**Bijective pairing** - what I know here is that bijective pairing between sets means for two sets X and Y a single value in X maps to a single value in Y and the inverse is also true

- If I am not mistaken the reason the encoding is a bijective pairing is because each one of the 4 numbers we will select will map to $\{a,b,c,d\}$ though I may be mistaken here

### Where my understanding fails me

A) I am not sure exactly what they mean by encoding and decoding but again I sort of have the assumption in my head that this is mapping each of the 4 numbers to either a b c or d.

B) I am not sure how understanding how to do this encoding will tie in to me being able to answer the last part of the question

Comment: Your question has several parts. The first part is straightforward. You are to count the number of ordered lists you describe. The rest is confusing. "codeword" has no formal definition independent of the context of your particular problem. Either you have been given or are supposed to invent a way to "encode" each sequence $a,b,c,d$ so that you can reconstruct the sequence from the word. One way would be to write the sequence as a list, with commas. Presumably you are expected to do something more useful. If you can [edit] the question to provide more information maybe we can help.

Comment: Hey Ethan thanks for the help in all honesty I was confused on that part too, I submitted the hw then came here wondering if there was some sort of principal I was missing on but it seems like I’m not able to find anything on this either. Someone earlier who I’m guessing is in my class that the professor left us a hint in the worksheet how to solve this but that hint honestly made no sense to me